# TableView UISearchBar Crashes while Searching

Tags: uitableview, nsmutablearray, uisearchbar, nsmutabledictionary

I've been playing around with a search facility for my application table view for a while now trying to get it working but i keep getting the same error in my console.

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' [NSCFDictionary rangeOfString:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

DataSource is an array which is taking itz value from a dictionary....
and tableData will be storing data that will be displayed in table.
Q:
Suppose I have a dictionary with 5 values each having different keys corresponding to those values.. then i put that dictionary in an array. Can that array be used as a dataSource for search? and i am using the same array in cellForRowAtIndexPath to display data on my cells.

*Plz suggest with code snippet.*

Here is my code for textDidChange

```
    -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
    {   
        [tableData removeAllObjects];// remove all data that belongs to previous search

        if([searchText isEqualToString:@""]){
            searchText==nil;
            [tableview reloadData];     
            return;     
        }

        NSInteger counter = 0;  
        for(NSString *name in dataSource)       
        {       
            NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];      
            NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];        
            if(r.location != NSNotFound)            
            {           
                if(r.location== 0)//that is we are checking only the start of the names.                
                {               
                    [tableData addObject:name];             
                }           
            }       
            counter++;      
            [pool release];     
        }   
        [tableview reloadData]; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with additional condition...

```
    if([searchText isEqualToString:@""] || searchText == nil){
    }
```

Let me know, does it work for you or not?

If dataSource would be your NSMutableArray....

```
    for (int i = 0; i < [dataSource count]; i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *temp = (NSMutableDictionary*) [dataSource objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [temp valueForKey:@"name"]];
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];      
        NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];        
        if(r.location != NSNotFound)            
        {           
            if(r.location== 0)//that is we are checking only the start of the names.                
            {               
                [tableData addObject:name];             
            }           
        }       
        counter++;      
        [pool release];
    }
```

Comment: **NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];**

Comment: What value **name** stores that is received from dataSource?

Comment: it stores the searched string value.

Comment: how you can search if your dataSource is a dictionary ?

Comment: It should be array of dictionaries

Comment: Suppose I have a dictionary with 5 values each having different keys corresponding to those values.. then i put that dictionary in an array. Can that array be used as a dataSource for search? and i am using the same array in cellForRowAtIndexPath to display data on my cells.

Comment: I have already posted the sample code as if the dataSource is an NSMutableArray.

Comment: It is not working. As indirectly my data Source is a dictionary might be the problem. when i try to write anything on search bar complete table is removed givin me no results. What should I do now?

Comment: This code is not helping me..I am taking dictionary data to an array and using that array to populate my tableview. using same array for search operations and it is showing me the above error.